# ParseException NoClassDefFoundExcpetion for json-simple

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, json-simple

I get this [ERROR](http://pastebin.com/2PGB5nCQ) even though I added the jar file to my build path.How can I get the json-simple library working again.

[image: Java Build Path->libraries]

[image: Java Build path->Order and Export]

Comment: Are you building tomcat project? Can you post a pictures that expand all your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problems before, copy your external jars to WEB-INF/lib and it will solve your problems.

[image]